# Passing arguments from c++ to assembly in cout

Tags: c++, assembly, nasm, argument-passing

I'm writing simple mix of c++ and nasm assembly atm and dont understand why the results are different inside and outside of the "cout". Maybe this is some kind of exception however I would like to know the difference.Thanks for any help.

C++ PART

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
extern "C" unsigned int quot (unsigned int, unsigned int);
extern "C" unsigned int remainder (unsigned int, unsigned int);

int main()
{
    unsigned int i=0, j=0, k=0;
    cout << "Numbers 'x y'" << endl;
    cin >> i >> j;
    k = quot(i,j);
    cout<< "Result: " <<k;
    k = remainder(i,j);
    cout <<" r. "<< k <<endl;

    cout << "Result: "<<quot(i,j)<<" r. "<<remainder(i,j)<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

NASM 
quot and reminder functions are almost the same. the only difference is commented in the code

```
section .data

section .text
    global quot

quot:
    ; intro 
    push ebp         
    mov ebp,esp      

    xor edx, edx     
    mov eax, [ebp+8] 
    mov ebx,[ebp+12] 

    div ebx

    ; DIFFERENCE: in remainder we have additionaly
    ; mov eax, edx

    mov esp,ebp 
    pop ebp  
    ret
```

RESULTS
For 12 5 input we expect Result: 2 r. 2 but we obtain.

```
Result: 2 r. 2
Result: 2 r. 5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to preserve value of `ebx` in your asm functions (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#cdecl). Violating the calling convention may result in various range of errors, from subtle to crashes.

Use `ecx` instead of `ebx`, or try `div dword ptr [ebp+12]`.